# flashpunk ui wont show

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

According to a tutorial on tuts+(http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-ui-components-for-flashpunk-games--active-11364), I have made everything so far to step 12. As I tried to test this Project nothing Pops up except the Default Flash Debugger which is actually blank. i'm not sure if the tutorial is too old or no longer compatible with Flashdevelop or flashpunk library. Btw. i'm working with an as 3 library called flashpunk.

What I seek: is that the ui Pops up according to that tutorial
Unfortunately I can not provide the code because of the code Format error. and I tried to press ctrl and k. and pasted my code in them but it still didnt work.
If possible, please add a working code snippet or a screenshot.
Thanks in advance.

The Output

Running process: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Gamesamples\UI\Flashpunk UI\UI.as3proj" -ipc 9ad09f9f-2fcd-467d-ab27-3e043421080f -version "4.6.0; 18.0" -compiler "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\FlashDevelop\Apps\flexairsdk\4.6.0+18.0.0" -library "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Library"
Building UI
mxmlc -load-config+=obj\UIConfig.xml -debug=true -incremental=true -swf-version=29 -o obj\UI635736784381832664
Starting java as: java.exe -Xmx384m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true -Dapplication.home="C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\FlashDevelop\Apps\flexairsdk\4.6.0+18.0.0" -jar "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\FlashDevelop\Apps\flexairsdk\4.6.0+18.0.0\lib\fcsh.jar"
INITIALIZING: Adobe Flex Compiler SHell (fcsh)
Starting new compile.
Loading configuration file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\FlashDevelop\Apps\flexairsdk\4.6.0+18.0.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml
Loading configuration file C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Gamesamples\UI\Flashpunk UI\obj\UIConfig.xml
obj\UI635736784381832664 (87932 bytes)
(fcsh)Build succeeded
Done(0)
[Starting debug session with FDB]

Comment: I followed the tutorial till step 12 and it is working properly. Please paste the contents of Output panel after the compilation.

Comment: Thx for your effort. I will check the tut again and hopefully get it right. Perhaps I have missed out some Details but I checked the tutorial  several times and my code. Afterall I dont see anything wrong compared to that tutorial.

Comment: Ugh found out the Problem, I overlooked a function and added it to my Button class -.- instead to my main.as